# How To Switch Tab Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here I am showing tabs with basic data. It will go to next tab whenever I click next tab button.

Can anybody help me how to switch tabs automatically after few seconds, like first 30 sec tab1,next 30 sec tab2 - after tab2 it should come to tab1

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
var updatedTime = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = updatedTime;
document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = updatedTime;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style tab links */

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#Home {
  background-color: red;
}

#News {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Last Updated On : <span id="time1"></span><br>
      <p>Software Version</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Last Updated On : <span id="time2"></span><br>
      <p>Software Version</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the time from your deleted answer to your code

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

I would perhaps clear the timeout if someone clicks any tab in case they want to stay on it

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it

  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tablink");
  let cnt = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    if (tabs[i].id === "defaultOpen") {
      cnt = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  tabs[cnt].click(); // clicks defaultOpen first time
  const tId = setInterval(function() {
    cnt++;
    if (cnt >= tabs.length) cnt = 0;
    tabs[cnt].click();
  }, 3000);

  const lmID = setInterval(function() {
    var updatedTime = document.lastModified;
    document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = updatedTime;
    document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = updatedTime;
  },1000)  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style tab links */

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#Home {
  background-color: red;
}

#News {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Last Updated On : <span id="time1"></span><br>
      <p>Software Version</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Last Updated On : <span id="time2"></span><br>
      <p>Software Version</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added last updated time at footer. it us not updating if we refresh the page then time is updating else tab is switching but time not updating

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Please update the question with relevant code

Comment: Why would a "last updated" change when you switch tabs? The page did not update

Comment: no actualy i added a footer to that page where we can show last updated  time using javascript. while i am switching page it is showing time but time not updating

Comment: i have edited and posted as my answer. can u please check

Comment: I have updated my answer with your code. I am not sure what you mean when you say the time does not update. It should only update when you have changed the page on the server

Comment: while switching tabs after 3 seconds , last updated time need to change. like at tab 1 we have 4:00:03  while we switch to tab2 it should be 4:00:06

Comment: That makes no sense. document.lastModified is NOT a clock. It is a value set by the server telling the browser when the page was last changed on the server. If you need it to be set all the time, you need to change the container values every second

Comment: I made the change. In real life on a real server, the value should be static